# Sejda Merge PDFs w/ Filelist

Tags: java, filelist, sejda

I'm trying to merge pdfs with an external CSV file.  The CSV file and all pdfs are in the same directory.  I've got the following code, but it keeps spitting back errors.

```
Call sejda-console.bat merge -f C:\temp -l C:\temp\book3.csv -o C:\temp\temp2.pdf
```

The tutorial uses calls for "[--filesListConfig -l value]", I'm just not sure if I'm using it right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Invalid value (A not null File instance that isFile is expected.): [--files -f value...]: pdf files to operate on: a list of existing pdf files (EX. -f /tmp/file1.pdf or -f \tmp\password_protected_file2.pdf:secret123) (optional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not provide `-f` and `-l` at the same time.

Here's an example that works (commands are Unix format):

```
./bin/sejda-console merge -l /tmp/files.csv  -o /tmp/output.pdf
```

And `files.csv` contains:

```
>  sejda-console-1.0.0.M9  $ cat /tmp/files.csv
/tmp/file1.pdf,/tmp/file2.pdf
```